AWS lambda logging garbage like Inside unicode_me(). val = "ATTRIBUTE_NAME"
I have an AWS lambda written in python that is mysteriously logging tons of garbage like this line:
Inside unicode_me(). val = "ATTRIBUTE_NAME"

The lines themselves say many different things, but they are all useless. My code is not doing this.
What is causing this and how do I make it stop?

https://github.com/quandyfactory/dicttoxml/issues/98
